# r xyplot "steps" centered on data points

Tags: r, lattice

the type argument to `xyplot()` can take "s" for "steps." From `help(plot)`:

> The two step types differ in their x-y preference: Going from
>        (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) with x1 < x2, 'type = "s"' moves first
>        horizontal, then vertical, whereas 'type = "S"' moves the other
>        way around.

i.e. if you use `type="s"`, the horizontal part of the step has its left end attached to the data point, while `type="S"` has its right end attached to the data point.

```
library(lattice)
set.seed(12345)
num.points <- 10
my.df <- data.frame(x=sort(sample(1:100, num.points)),
                    y=sample(1:40, num.points, replace=TRUE))

xyplot(y~x, data=my.df, type=c("p","s"), col="blue", main='type="s"')
xyplot(y~x, data=my.df, type=c("p","S"), col="red", main='type="S"')
```

[image: type='s']

[image: type='S']

How could one achieve a "step" plot, where the vertical motion happens between data points points, i.e. at `x1 + (x2-x1)/2`, so that the horizontal part of the step is centered on the data point?

Edited to include some example code. better late than never I suppose.

Comment: Do you necessarily need `lattice` or would base R work?

Comment: I'm deep into something that uses `lattice`, so it is highly preferred, but a base graphics fallback plan wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: I would consider plotting with `panel.xyplot` using col="white" if you do not want the circle-points (which would set up the coordinate system) and then plotting with `panel.lines` using type="s" with a suitable offset. (I'm boycotting questions that have no example code so someone else is welcome to adopt this strategy if it has merit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using excellent @nico answer to give its lattice version. Even I am ok with @Dwin because the question don't supply a reproducible example, but customizing lattice panel is sometimes challenging.
The idea is to use `panel.segments` which is the equivalent of `segments` of base graphics.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(y~x,
       panel =function(...){
         ll <- list(...)
         x <- ll$x
         y <- ll$y
         x.start <- x - (c(0, diff(x)/2))
         x.end   <- x + (c(diff(x)/2, 0))
         panel.segments(x.start, y, x.end, y, col="orange", lwd=2)
         panel.segments(x.end[-length(x.end)], y[1:(length(y)-1)], 
                        x.end[-length(x.end)], y[-1], col="orange", lwd=2)
         ## this is optional just to compare with type s
         panel.xyplot(...,type='s')
         ## and type S
         panel.xyplot(...,type='S')
       })
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a base graphics solution, as I am not too much of an expert in `lattice`.

Essentially you can use `segments` to draw first the horizontal, then the vertical steps, passing the shifted coordinates as a vector.

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(12345)

# Generate some data
num.points <- 10
x <- sort(sample(1:100, num.points))
y <- sample(1:40, num.points, replace=T)


# Plot the data with style = "s" and "S"
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

plot(x, y, "s", col="red", lwd=2, las=1, 
     main="Style: 's'", xlim=c(0, 100))
points(x, y, pch=19, col="red", cex=0.8)

plot(x, y, "S", col="blue", lwd=2, las=1, 
     main="Style: 'S'", xlim=c(0, 100))
points(x, y, pch=19, col="blue", cex=0.8)

# Now plot our points
plot(x, y, pch=19, col="orange", cex=0.8, las=1, 
     main="Centered steps", xlim=c(0, 100))

# Calculate the starting and ending points of the
# horizontal segments, by shifting the x coordinates
# by half the difference with the next point
# Note we leave the first and last point as starting and
# ending points
x.start <- x - (c(0, diff(x)/2))
x.end <- x + (c(diff(x)/2, 0))

# Now draw the horizontal segments
segments(x.start, y, x.end, y, col="orange", lwd=2)
# and the vertical ones (no need to draw the last one)
segments(x.end[-length(x.end)], y[1:(length(y)-1)], 
         x.end[-length(x.end)], y[-1], col="orange", lwd=2)
```

Here is the result:
[image: Step plots]